# "To delete" is to "deletion" as "to discard" is to what?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

"To delete" is to "deletion" as "to discard" is to what?

Comment: There's a reason those character count requirements are in place. The question you're asking should always be included in the body of the text, not only in the title. And adding a bit of verbosity, rather than ranting and raving inappropriately, is not that difficult. -1.

Comment: It also reduces the quality of the prose.

Comment: Discard is like any other verb: you get a noun by adding *-ing*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing that is deleted is a *deletion*; the thing that is discarded is a *discard*.

The act of deleting is a *deletion*; the act of *discarding* is a *discarding*.

If you like using incredibly rare words, you can use *discardure* for the act of discarding, as Jon Hanna's answer says. Expect people to think it's not a real word.

Comment: Isn't this attitude the one that cements the extinction of already rare words?

Comment: If we go by usage, it's not clear to me whether *discardal* or *discardure* is the correct noun. Using search tools, they seem roughly equally frequent, with *discardal* having a slight edge. (See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discardal%2Cdiscardure+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscardal%3B%2Cc0).) I don't know why one appears in dictionaries and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

*[Discardure](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discardure)*, though it is not a common word, used primarily in legal contexts.